# What is causing this Null Pointer Exception?

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to get song add and delete functionality working for hypothetical playlists for a hypothetical song database.

The first time I call the `deleteSong()` function to delete a song from a Playlist object it works fine. The second time I call the function, upon selecting the index of the playlist to delete a song from, it attempts to run the `selectSong()` function where it initiates the for loop to print each song, but apparently the `songs[]` array becomes full of nulls, or at least element 0 is a null, as it throws the `NullpointerException` on the first iteration (`i = 0`).

The `logicalSize` variable is pretty self explanatory. It tracks how many actual initialized Song objects there are in the array.

Note: This is basically copy/pasted code from making the same function for my Playlist objects (adding and deleting playlists) and I haven't encountered this issue.

Here are the methods:

```
public void deleteSong(int index){
    System.out.println("[INFO] Deleting the selected song...");
    Song[] tempSongs = new Song[songs.length-1];
    tempSongs[tempSongs.length-1] = new Song();
    if (index+1 > songs.length-1){
      System.out.println("[INFO] Song item is last element.");
      for (int i=0;i<tempSongs.length;i++){
          tempSongs[i] = songs[i];
      }
    } else {
      //songs[index+1] = songs[index];
      for (int i=index;i<tempSongs.length;i++){
        if (i == index){
            System.out.println("[INFO] Song: skip index to remove");
        } else {
            tempSongs[i] = songs[i+1];
        }
      }    
  }

  songs = tempSongs;
  logicalSize--;
}
```

code for adding a song:

```
public void addSong(Song song)
{

    songs[logicalSize] = new Song();
    songs[logicalSize]= song;
    logicalSize++;
    songCount++;

}
```

selectSong() function:

```
public int selectSong()
{
    Scanner menu = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i=0;i<logicalSize;i++){ 
        System.out.println("[" + i + "] Title: " + songs[i].getName() + " Artist: " + songs[i].getArtist());
    }
    System.out.println("Select a song by entering its song number (0, 1, 2...).");
    int songChoice = menu.nextInt();
    return songChoice;

}
```

Comment: Perhaps adding the output would help.

Comment: Please add the stacktrace to your question.

Comment: I know I'm not going to be of help but have you tried to stick a breakpoint in and stepping through your code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/3165552

Answer (score 0):

You initialize `newsongs` to an array full of `null` Song references. Then in the case that you're not removing the last song, you only start initializing `newsongs` at position `index+1`. All the prior entries are still null.

Unless this is an assignment or a learning exercise, you really ought to learn about Java's `List` type and its implementations. [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is the Java 7 javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to use an `ArrayList`?

You can define an ArrayList of Song and use the methods `yourList.add()` and `yourList.remove()`. You can remove an item with its index or with an object

It will be something like this

```
ArrayList<Song> yourList = new ArrayList¸<Song>();
```

[ArrayList Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

```
public E remove(int index)
public boolean remove(Object o)
```